# Nuxt.JS express, почему возвращает html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nuxt.js

Всем привет, пытаюсь реализовать подобие API

Использую nuxtjs+express

В папке server, файл index.js прописываю

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
res.send({ method: 'GET' })
})
```

Пытаюсь обратится по данному адресу через fetch и postman.

Но возвращается почему то разметка страницы, почему так происходит?

код server/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }
  app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ method: 'GET' })
  })
  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server has been started on port: http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Запустил у себя ваш скрипт, вроде работает нормально. Страница `http://localhost:3000/test` возвращает JSON документ `{"method":"GET"}`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]